# При падении сервера, сайт не работает до перезагрузки браузера

Tags: jquery, ajax, сеть, rest

Есть клиент-северное приложение, в котором в качестве интерфейса между клиентом и сервером используется REST API. Проблема в том, что сервер бывает перегружен и по этой причине стоит timeout(500 мс) по истечению которого делает повторный запрос. С каждым повторным запросом интервал увеличивается...

Все хорошо, но проблема в том, в консоле дальше выдаются ошибки (о том, что сервер не доступный), но если зайти с другого браузера проблемы нет(до определенной момента). Как это можно исправить? Может проблема в каком-то кэше, если да, то как можно исправить? В качестве API для AJAX использую jQuery.

Если этот же браузер закрыть и открыть, то проблема тоже пропадет. Тестировал на Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Нельзя ли дописать что то "keep alive" функции до загрузки основной серверной части, которая будет оповещать клиентам что сервер "грузится"?

Comment: @Hellseher, так и есть, но проблема остается